# C# Regex doesn't match but regex testers do match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

```
 var pattern = @"[\S\s][0-9]{1,}\e[0-9]{1,}";
 var regEx = new Regex(pattern);
```

This yields zero matches when run against this string:

"Show name - s01e08 - Episode name.mp4"

These regex testers get a match:
http://www.regexr.com/
http://regexpal.com/

but this one that clams to be a .Net regex tester does not get a match:
http://regexhero.net/tester/

Which is what I am experiencing in my app.

1. Why is there a difference?
2. How do I 'fix' my regex pattern to get a match in my C# app?

---

Sidenote:
The actual pattern I would like to use is:

"[\S\s][0-9]{1,}[\E\e][0-9]{1,}"

But this gives me a 'Unrecognized escape sequence \E.' error in both the .Net regex tester and my C# app.
I will create a new SO question for this but wanted to mention it here as I'm sure someone will notice my original pattern will not catch upper case 'E'.

Comment: What do you expect `\e` or `\E` to do?

Comment: [\S\s] is just like .

Comment: @ScottChamberlain match on either 'E' or 'e'

Comment: Only escape sequences should have a leading slash. [Here is the list of them](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx), `\s` does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write a RegEx for .NET without really using its syntax. .NET does not use Posix syntax is what you might be using.

Some mistakes that I can call:

- When you want to match a letter, you should not espace it. You don't need any \ before it. To match an upper case E, just use E
- \s matches whitespace in .NET. If you want to match a lowercase s, just write s

Here is what your pattern means:

```
[\S\s] match one space character (\s) or one non-whitespace character (\S)
[0-9]{1,} match a digit (0 to 9) 1 times or more
\e match one escape character
[0-9]{1,} match a digit one or more times
```

Comment: Ah ha! That was it. I was over thinking it. Thanks! Will accept when time limit expires.

Comment: Also, `{1,}` can be shortened to `+`

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern should be

```
[sS](?<Season>\d+)[eE](?<Episode>\d+)
```

You basically do not have to escape characters inside range specifiers, and `\d+` is a more concise way of writing `[0-9]{1,}`

Comment: Great point, using escape chars inside [Ranges] can cause poor matching results.